# ld: library not found for -lFlurryWithLocation

Tags: xcode, clang, mach-o

I just check out an old project from SVN for my work and when I tried to build it, i got 6 errors.
I can't resolve 2 of 'em.
So the first one is about the Flurry library.

here is the error : 
"I replaced the name of the app buy APPNAME"

```
Ld /Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/APPNAME normal i386
    cd "/Users/MYNAME/Documents/Projects/APPFOLDER/APPNAME"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Intermediates/APPNAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.build/Objects-normal/i386/APPNAME.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30100 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lsqlite3.0 -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework CoreLocation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework MessageUI -lFlurryWithLocation -o /Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/APPNAME

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: library not found for -lFlurryWithLocation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried to find a solution anywhere on the web but I don't...
Then, the next error is : 
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app.dSYM /Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/APPNAME
    cd "/Users/MYNAME/Documents/Projects/APPFOLDER/APPNAME"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/APPNAME -o /Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app.dSYM

error: unable to open executable '/Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-ewdtviqnemaxivekjlajlxqanwvm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/APPNAME'
```

Can somebody help me please..?
I have no more idea..

Comment: So is the 'FlurryLocation' library installed on your system?

Comment: yes it is. In my folder and in my "Link Binary" Build Phases

Comment: And have you tried to resolve the 'ld: : warning: directory not found' error message?

Comment: RECTIFICATION : Xcode's trying to find an Xcode.app in Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Applications but it doesn't exists....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the SVN specifically included the libflurryanalytics.a library (which it probably didn't because svn sees .a files as binary files and ignores them).

Download and include the libFlurryAnalytics.a from their website and include it in your target. http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html

You can then add the file into SVN using:

```
svn add "libFlurryAnalytics.a" --no-ignore
```

Comment: Have you added it to your target under linked frameworks and libraries?

Comment: Yes got it in my Ling Binary in Build Phases.

Comment: Make sure you are using the most current flurry sdk, sounds like older versions split up the location management into a different library.

Comment: Is there a link between my old libFlurryWithLocation.a and https://www.flurry.com/ ?? I don't know where they got that lib